# Create temp table using JDatabaseQuery

Tags: joomla

Is it possible to create a create (and delete) temporary tables using the JDatabaseQuery class? I would like to be able to do something like

```
$db = $this->getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->drop('`#__temp_standings`');
$query->create('#_temp_standings`');
$query->select('home AS school, gamedate');
etc, etc,
```

I've looked through libraries/joomla/database/query.php and it doesn't look possible to me, but I have missed the obvious before. Using Joomla! 3.3.0.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop a table using Joomla's API like so:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->dropTable('#__temp_standings');
$db->setQuery($query);
```

As for creating a table, I'm not aware of any methods using the Joomla API, therefore I think you could use something like this:

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__temp_standings`";
```

If anyone knows of another methods then please do share as I would also be interested.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the dropTable.